# Unable to get access token from google calender apI ios

Tags: ios, google-calendar-api

Unable to get to access token from google calender API

I am using google calendar ,how can i get access token when user already login.

```
// Display the start dates and event summaries in the UITextView
func displayResultWithTicket(
    ticket: GTLServiceTicket,
    finishedWithObject response : GTLCalendarEvents,
                       error : NSError?) {
    if let error = error {
        showAlert("Error", message: error.localizedDescription)
        return
    }

    print(service.authorizer)

    var eventString = ""

    if let events = response.items() where !events.isEmpty {
        for event in events as! [GTLCalendarEvent] {
            let start : GTLDateTime! = event.start.dateTime ?? event.start.date
            let startString = NSDateFormatter.localizedStringFromDate(
                start.date,
                dateStyle: .ShortStyle,
                timeStyle: .ShortStyle
            )
            eventString += "\(startString) - \(event.summary)\n"
        }
    } else {
        eventString = "No upcoming events found."
    }

    output.text = eventString
}
```

print(service.authorizer)

output :

```
 GTMOAuth2Authentication 0x7fae3d9cc9a0: {accessToken="ya29.CjBCA3-uM-b2vtbvFtYgfS5anHIVaRc7NwHY4pD9uPQEj2phoqk1yjd-TNnsWEz_nSQ", refreshToken="1/pBtww6SXoUZv_9l9L0C4QGGvNoqVWMdIDvCWXeI9Uco", expirationDate="2016-08-17 06:51:43 +0000"}
```

How get i get access token from this?

I get the acessToken using this code: -

```
 print(service.authorizer.description)
    let json = service.authorizer.description
    let array = json.componentsSeparatedByString("\"")
    print(array[1])
```

but i don't think this is the best way to do this , can any one suggest better solution for this problem

Comment: can you show ur tried code

Comment: i have updated my code